# repository pattern of golang-echo-realworld-example-app

Tags: go

I am developing my personal project, referring to [golang-echo-realworld-example-app](https://github.com/xesina/golang-echo-realworld-example-app) But I have some points which I don't still understand about this example projet.

- How do you call this repository pattern?
- Is this any design pattern? This seems like an adapter pattern to me.
- Does this have Store interface of user and article in order to mock it for testing? [link here](https://github.com/xesina/golang-echo-realworld-example-app/blob/master/user/user.go)

Comment: Whether or not it's a "pattern", and if so, which kind, is a question of your definition. If it's happened at least twice or three times, it can be called a pattern. How, and if, you label that pattern is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Is there an actual problem you're trying to solve? This looks like primarily a taxonomy question, which probably is not ["a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thank you for commenting on my question. I want to enhance my knowledge from the repository. There is not any problem for solving it. I'm sorry for asking bad question. I should close this question.

Comment: Improving knowledge is good, and can make for good questions. But the question should be focused, and not based on opinions.